# Android Intent filter using data path

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, intentfilter

I'm making messaging app. 
I want to push message to specific chatroom by using broadcast.
I though uri.

```
chat://chatroom/{room name}
```

And I send a message to room name 7777.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_CHAT);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("chat://chatroom/7777"));
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And I regestered a broadcastreceiver with intent filter like below..
But I can't receive message.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_UPDATE_CHAT);
filter.addDataScheme("chat");
filter.addDataAuthority("chatroom", null);
filter.addDataPath("7777", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_LITERAL);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Please Help!! :)

---

updated.
I can receive br when i remove this line.

```
filter.addDataPath("7777", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_LITERAL);
```

But If then..Every chat room receive br..

Answer (score 1):

When you send broadcast,the intent action is `ACTION_UPDATE_DATA`,but when you receive broadcast,the intent action is `ACTION_UPDATE_CHAT`,maybe it's why you can't receive the message.

Comment: Thanks!  For your help. I modified you mentioned. But still It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

`filter.addDataPath("7777", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_LITERAL);`

by

`filter.addDataPath("/7777", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_LITERAL);`

The change is very subtle. All I did was add a "/" before "7777". This will fix it.